# How to build logout request using okhttp?

Tags: java, django-rest-framework, jwt, okhttp

I am using Simple_JWT for authentication in Djangorestframework back-end. when a user is logged in the following url will log them out:

http://130.50.85.130/rest-auth/logout/

it requires no data.

now I am trying to post similar request using Okhttp. 
When I am trying the following, it breaks:

```
Request post_request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url_str)
        .addHeader("Authorization", "JWT "+token)
        .build();
```

Note that it doesn't have a body and it has token in the header. I am not sure if this post request needs any body or needs header containing token. 
I guess the bottom line of my question is how to send a request for log out using okhttp from a user that is already signed in,
Please advise,
Thanks,

Comment: Logout request is nothing but another rest call. You have to invoke your rest call similar to other request. Please post "what breaks" to help further .

Comment: Once a JWT is created and issued, it can not be canceled thereafter.
To implement logout, you can remove the JWT from the client side.
If you must implement to prevent bad users, you should create blacklists on the server side.